# Skip the remaining tasks within airflow Dag if s3senors is not able to find the file

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

Is there a way I can skip remaining tasks within a dag if s3sensor operator is not able to find the file in s3 location.

I know that we can use shortcircuit operator to skip the task, but I am looking for a way in which I can integrate shortcircuit and s3sensor operator together. If not, then is there any other way I can achieve that? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that the sensor operator fails due to a timeout when you say "is not able to find the file in s3 location", there is an implicit way to handle this through the Airflow Scheduler.

You can use the `soft_fail` parameter available to all of the sensor operators that inherit from the [BaseSensorOperator](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/apache-airflow/modules/basesensoroperator) (which all of the S3 sensors do). If `soft_fail` is set to True, the sensor operator will be set to a "skipped" state when the sensor fails for a timeout rather than being set to a state of "failed".

If the downstream tasks do not have a `trigger_rule` to allowing them to execute when an upstream task is set to "skipped" (the default `trigger_rule` is "all_success" -- more on Trigger Rules [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html?highlight=trigger%20rule#concepts-trigger-rules)), the Scheduler will mark the downstream tasks as "skipped" as well. This will continue to propagate down the DAG.

Basically the Scheduler looks at the downstream tasks' `trigger_rule` and sees that they should not run because upstream tasks were "skipped" and then subsequently skips the tasks.